# Dropdown is overloading

Tags: html, css

In IE8,Dropdown is overloading to the another Div 
Here I use the following CSS

```css
background-color:#f7f7f7;
font:12px arial;
color:#999999;
width:240px;
display:none;
z-index:999999;
position:absolute;
top:20px;
border-left:1px solid #d8d8d8;
border-right:1px solid #d8d8d8;
margin-left:40px;
```

please help me.

Thanks

Comment: You'll have to add some HTML, and also, something you've tried doing to solve the problem. Consider demonstrating the problem on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 0):

remove this lines

```
position:absolute;
top:20px;
```

and look at http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp